# Using a String variable to refer to an object field

Tags: java, reflection

I have a Book object with several different String fields (title, author, subject...), and I am deigning a GUI to display each of these fields for a collection of books. I have a panel on which I want to have, for each field, a label (naming the field), a TextField (which displays the value stored in the field), and an edit button, which makes the TextField editable and displays a second button to save any edits made.

Rather than coding each of these into the panel individually, I would like to create a "field panel" with a single label, TextField and button. Then I want to use a foreach loop to create one of these panels for each field (stored in a list) and load these panels into the main panel.

I know that the following is not possible:

```
Book b = new Book();
String[] fieldTitles = {title, author, subject, publisher};
for (String str : fieldTitles) { 
    FieldPanel fp = new FieldPanel();
    fp.namelabel.settext(str);
    fp.textField.settext(b.str);
}
```

But is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do here on the last line, which is to use a named String variable to refer to a field of an object? In other words, I want to do: `objectInstance.stringVariable` (where stringVariable matches the name of a field of the objectInstance.

Comment: With reflection and the class `Field`.

Comment: you can use reflections for that. but I wouldn't recommend it, because the compiler can't show you possible syntax errors that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for reflection. There's a [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) on the subject that will get you started, and then there are many, many libraries out there to make reflection easier, like [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//) and several of the classes in [Spring's util package](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/package-summary.html). Pretty much any framework out there will have some kind of reflection helper class in it because it's so messy to work directly with reflection.

As a quick example for your case, using [Commons BeanUtils.getProperty()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#getProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29), you could say:

```
fp.textField.settext((String) BeanUtils.getProperty(b, str));
```

Here's a complete example doing it the manual way so you can see how it fits in:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class BasicReflectionGettingFieldValues {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FieldPanel fp = new FieldPanel();
        Book b = new Book("Mostly Harmless", "Douglas Adams");
        for (String str : Arrays.asList("author", "title")) {
            fp.namelabel.settext(str);
            fp.textField.settext(getField(b, str));
        }
    }

    private static String getField(Book b, String str) {
        try {
            Field field = Book.class.getDeclaredField(str);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            return (String) field.get(b);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Bad field name: " + str, e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to access field " + str + " after making it accessible", e);
        }
    }

    static class Book {
        private String title;
        private String author;

        Book(String title, String author) {
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
        }
    }
    static class TextField {
        void settext(String s) {
            System.out.println("Setting text field to '" + s + "'");
        }
    }
    static class NameLabel {
        void settext(String s) {
            System.out.println("Setting name label to '" + s + "'");
        }
    }
    static class FieldPanel {
        private NameLabel namelabel = new NameLabel();
        private TextField textField = new TextField();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. This is the subject we're supposed to be covering in my class this week. Would it be possible for you to give a me a brief sudocode example of how I could use reflection in this situation? It would help me wrap my head around a concept that I thus-far only understand in the abstract

Comment: So, in your BeanUtils example, b is the Book instance and str is the string used in the for loop? What would the ugly manual way look like? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Accidentally submitted the partial edit before. The manual way is there now :)